# Connecting Lightning Data Service to apex controler

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-data-service

I'm having trouble implementing a solution when using an action in the account context, calling a component that passes certain fields to an apex controller. The idea is to use Lightning data service.

This is the component I have so far:

```
<aura:component controller="CallInformaDBController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader, force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="simpleAccount" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accountError" type="String"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="accountRecordLoader"
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        fields="Name,NIF__c"
        targetRecord="{!v.account}"
        targetFields="{!v.simpleAccount}"
        targetError="{!v.accountError}"
        recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
    />



</aura:component>
```

More specifically, How do I access the fields Name and Nif__c in the Javascript controller?

Comment: What is your specific question about using Lightning Data Service? It looks like you have declared the component correctly. Can you edit your question to include a specific issue or error message you're struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to access the loaded fields is via the component attribute named in the `targetFields` attribute of the `force:recordData` component. Say you're in a JavaScript controller method; you'd do something like this:

```
doSomething: function(component, event, helper) {
    // ... do things ...

    var accountName = component.get('v.simpleAccount').Name;

    // ... continue processing, run Apex server method, etc ... 
},
```

Keep in mind that `force:recordData` loads data *asynchronously*. Your record is *not* guaranteed to be loaded at the point that your component's `init` handler goes off (or at any other point, for that matter), so be aware that you may not always have access to populated values.